# excel find index in tabular with search for ANY number in the origin with match in the target tabular

Tags: excel

I use `index` with `match` very often in Excel. However now I need something more difficult.

I have a list of numbers from which I want to find any in the target tabular

This looks like this (separatet with CR or ,)

- 420331-000-000, 420332-000-000, 420333-000-000, 420334-000-000

The target tabular contains only one number of these and in an other column the value of interest

- 420333-000-000, value of interest

If I try the typcial match, index it does not work since I can not find a direct match:

=INDEX(Eval[Short Name],MATCH([@OrderNr],Eval[SAPID],0))

I need an idea how to search for ANY of the IDs in the target tabular.

Here a sample Excel screenshot

[image]

The column B shall show the result of column E.

Comment: Do you have a visual representation of sample data on how your data looks, with searchvalues and prefered results? I had an answer, but I removed it since I doubt it was right...

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: I have edited my previously deleted answer. Hopefully it's still usefull. I tried to give you the option to return all results concatenated through commas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use the `SEARCH` function included in `MATCH`:

```
=INDEX($E$2:$E$3,MATCH(TRUE,SEARCH($D$2:$D$3,A2)>0))
```

This is array formula - after editing confirm it by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Thank you. In my case the formula is build with headers: `=INDEX(Eval[Ergebnis];VERGLEICH(WAHR();SUCHEN(Eval[SAPID];[@OrderNr])>0))`

Answer (score 1):

One way of dealing with this issue would be `TEXTJOIN` and `FILTERXML` combo to retrieve **all** hits concatenated with a comma instead of just a single result. For example:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",1,IF(Tabl1[SAPID]=TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE([@[Order Nr]],",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")),Table1[Result],""))
```

**Note:** This is an array formula and needs to be confirmed through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>